# Challenging regular expression

Tags: regex

There is a string in the following format:

- It can start with any number of strings enclosed by double braces, **possibly** with white space between them (whitespace may or may not occur).
- It may also contain strings enclosed by double-braces in the middle.

I am looking for a regular expression that can separate the start from the rest.

For example, given the following string:

```
{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij
```

The two parts are:

```
{{a}}{{b}} {{c}}
def{{g}}hij
```

I tried this:

```
/^({{.*}})(.*)$/
```

But, it captured also the g in the middle:

```
{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}
hij
```

I tried this:

```
/^({{.*?}})(.*)$/
```

But, it captured only the first a:

```
{{a}}
{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij
```

Comment: Are the characters inside braces alphanumeric (A-Za-z0-9_). Is the end defined by a non-{{something}} character. And will there will be only one whitespace.

Comment: @HighBoots Strings don't have to be alpha numeric. The end of the start is defined by something that is not in {{}}. There can be more than one whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This keeps matching `{{`, any non `{` or `}` character 1 or more times, `}}`, possible whitespace zero or more times and stores it in the first group. Rest of the string will be in the 2nd group. If there are no parts surrounded by `{{` and `}}` the first group will be empty. This was in JavaScript.

```
var str = "{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij";

str.match(/^\s*((?:\{\{[^{}]+\}\}\s*)*)(.*)/)

// [whole match, group 1, group 2]
// ["{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij", "{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} ", "def{{g}}hij"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

```
var string = "{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij";

console.log(string.match(/((\{\{\w+\}\})\s*)+/g));

// Output: [ '{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} ', '{{g}}' ]
```

Explanation:

1. `(` starts a group.
2. `(` another;
3. `\{\{\w+\}\}` looks for `{{A-Za-z_0-9}}`
4. `)` closes second group.
5. `\s*` Counts whitespace if it's there.
6. `)+` closes the first group and looks for oits one or more occurrences.

When it gets any `not-{{something}}` type data, it stops.

P.S. -> [Complex RegEx takes CPU speed.](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=709991675708445)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$str = '{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij';
$list = preg_split('/(\s[^{].+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($list);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{a}}{{b}} {{c}}
    [1] =>  def{{g}}hij
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

(java)

```
string[] result = yourstr.split("\\s+(?!{)");
```

(php)

```
$result = preg_split('/\s+(?!{)/', '{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij');
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I tried this in PHP: **preg_split("/\\s+(?!{)/", $mystr);** It didn't work - I got my entire example string in a single chunk.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: Sorry but You didn't mention the language you use with tags. To make it work with php remove a backslash.

Comment: You are right, it works for this exact string, but, if I remove the single space before "def", it returns the entire string in a single chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know exactly why are you want to split, but in case that the string contains always a def inside, and you want to separate the string from there in two halves, then, you can try something like:

```
string text = "{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} def{{g}}hij";

            Regex r = new Regex("def");
            string[] split = new string[2];
            int index = r.Match(text).Index;
            split[0] = string.Join("", text.Take(index).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray<string>());
            split[1] = string.Join("", text.Skip(index).Take(text.Length - index).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray<string>());
```

// Output: [ '{{a}}{{b}} {{c}} ', 'def{{g}}hij' ]

Comment: "def" is only an example.... The strings inside and between the braces can be any strings.

Comment: Oh, Ok! Then forget my answer :P Thanks for the info!